# For loop returns nothing React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So, I have a component which must loop from 0 to *entered value, given as a prop*

```
  if (props.number !== "" && props.toPow !== "") {
    for (let i; i < props.toPow; i++) {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>
            {props.number} ^ {i} = {Math.pow(props.number, i)}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    return <h3>Fill in all fields</h3>;
  }
```

but React says:

> Error: Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually
> means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return
> null.

Comment: unconditional `return` in a for loop means the loop will run exactly once and once only

Comment: but your loop is never entered ... perhaps you need to initialise `i` before comparing it, since `undefined < 10` (or any number) is always FALSE - therefore your loop does not run at all - however, your loop will still run exactly once at most

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right, much thanks!

Comment: I'm always right :D (don't tell my wife)

Comment: @JaromandaX if you're always right, than can you tell me what should I do, to make this loop run not once. I have already moved this code in a function, and run this function from the loop, also made a if (1) { ...then... }, but nothing worked :*(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
if (props.number !== "" && props.toPow !== "") {
    let powers =  Array.from({length:props.toPow}, (_, i) => (
        <span>
            {props.number} ^ {i} = {Math.pow(props.number, i)}
        </span>
    ));
    return <div>{powers}</div>;
} else {
    return <h3>Fill in all fields</h3>;
}
```

That would produce

```
<div>
    <span> .... </span>
    <span> .... </span>
    <span> .... </span>
</div>
```

If you need

```
<div>
    <span> .... </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span> .... </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span> .... </span>
</div>
```

Then you can do

```
if (props.number !== "" && props.toPow !== "") {
    let powers =  Array.from({length:props.toPow}, (_, i) => (
        </div>
            <span>
                {props.number} ^ {i} = {Math.pow(props.number, i)}
            </span>
        </div>
    ));
    return <>{powers}</>;
} else {
    return <h3>Fill in all fields</h3>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this :). Hope it will work...
I have added an empty array and just pushing the html into that and then returning whole array.

```
if (props.number !== "" && props.toPow !== "") {
  let arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < props.toPow; i++) {
    arr.push(
      <div key={i}>
        <span>
          {props.number} ^ {i} = {Math.pow(props.number, i)}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return arr
} else {
  return <h3>Fill in all fields</h3>
}
```

Comment: You 'll need to add a key to the div

Comment: Actually it was obvious @Aprillion for the user to put that data. The issue was it is returning nothing. So the post is related to that

Comment: the issue of returning nothing was because OP had `let i;` rather than `let i = 0;` - which you've since corrected, which was the point of the comment

Comment: plus, does react allow you to return multiple elements (at the top level)?

Comment: well, I did not know that :p